# I can't see comboboxes in a simple class. How to solve?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter

I created a class specifically for 2 comboboxes, but I can't see them. I am not receiving errors, but the 2 comboboxes are not displayed.

I don't need a class for the whole window, but I just need a class for those 2 comboboxes.

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve? Can you show me come? Thank you

```
import tkinter as tk                    
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
  
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tab Widget")
root.geometry('230x330')

conn = sqlite3.connect('database')
cursor = conn.cursor()   

class seleziona_squadra():
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('database')
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def fill_voyage(self):
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT campionato FROM BASE_ProssimaGiornata')
        self.result=[row[0] for row in self.cursor]
        return self.result

    def combo_campionato(self, event=None):
        global campionato
        self.val = self.campionato.get()
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT team_home||"-"||team_away FROM BASE_ProssimaGiornata WHERE  Campionato = ?', (self.val,))
        self.values = [row[0] for row in self.cursor] 
        global partita
        self.partita['value'] = self.values
        return self.values

    def seleziona(self, event=None):
        self.select_partita = self.partita.get()
            
        if self.select_partita:
            global squadra_sinistra
            global squadra_destra
            self.squadra_sinistra, self.squadra_destra = self.select_partita.split('-')


    self.campionato=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 25)
    self.campionato['value'] = self.fill_voyage()
    self.campionato.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.combo_campionato)
    self.campionato.place(x=1, y=1)

    self.partita=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 25)
    self.partita.place(x=1, y=30)
    self.partita.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.seleziona)

    self.combo_campionato()
    self.seleziona()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your combo box creation code has to be in the class init function. Then in your main code, you create an instance of that class which automatically shows UI elements created by that class. A cleaner approach would be to have your class in another file or just at the end or start of your code. It doesn't have to be in the middle of your code.

Here is the code (I commented out things that were causing errors)

```
import tkinter as tk                    
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
  
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tab Widget")
root.geometry('230x330')

conn = sqlite3.connect('database')
cursor = conn.cursor()   

class seleziona_squadra():
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('database')
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

        self.campionato=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 25)
        self.campionato['value'] = self.fill_voyage()
        self.campionato.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.combo_campionato)
        self.campionato.place(x=1, y=1)

        self.partita=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 25)
        self.partita.place(x=1, y=30)
        self.partita.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.seleziona)

        self.combo_campionato()
        self.seleziona()

    def fill_voyage(self):
        # self.cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT campionato FROM BASE_ProssimaGiornata')
        self.result=[row[0] for row in self.cursor]
        return self.result

    def combo_campionato(self, event=None):
        global campionato
        self.val = self.campionato.get()
        # self.cursor.execute('SELECT team_home||"-"||team_away FROM BASE_ProssimaGiornata WHERE  Campionato = ?', (self.val,))
        self.values = [row[0] for row in self.cursor] 
        global partita
        self.partita['value'] = self.values
        return self.values

    def seleziona(self, event=None):
        self.select_partita = self.partita.get()
            
        if self.select_partita:
            global squadra_sinistra
            global squadra_destra
            self.squadra_sinistra, self.squadra_destra = self.select_partita.split('-')


seleziona_squadra()

root.mainloop()
```